# My ubuntu 18.04.2 lts is not picking up game disks

Tags: games

I want to install a game cd on Ubuntu, but Ubuntu does not pick it up. I can however pick up normal DVD's and so on. But not game cd. Do I need to install drivers or what must I do?

Comment: Please define "does not pick it up". Can't read the contents or can't install? In any  case is not  a matter of drivers.

Comment: It spins a bit, then it stops. And doesn't appear or show up in Ubuntu. Other disks I don't have this issue

Comment: You mean it can read other data CDs? Or just music CDs? Or just DVDs?